# How to keep the previous value in intent extra when the app received new notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to get a unique id from firebase message response when i a received notification, and store it to intent using `intent.putExtras`. The problem is the unique id that i got from the first notification will get replaced with a new one from the second notification. Is there a workaround to handle this problem ?
The unique id is used to open a room (activity).

**FireBaseService.java**

```
public class FirebaseService extends QiscusFirebaseService {
    private AppComponent component;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message);
        Log.d("msg", "onMessageReceived: " + message.getData().get("room_id"));
        //UNIQUE ID I TRY TO GET
        String roomId = message.getData().get("room_id");
        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomePageTabActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
        intent.putExtra("roomId", roomId);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        String channelId = "Default";
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(message.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(message.getData().get("body"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        manager.notify(m, builder.build());
    }
    public AppComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

**HomePageTabActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        this.setIntent(intent);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            if(extras.containsKey("fromNotification") || extras.containsKey("roomId")) {
                openChatRoom(Long.valueOf(extras.getString("roomId")));
            }else if(extras.containsKey("fromNotification") && extras.containsKey("roomId")){
                openChatRoom(Long.valueOf(extras.getString("roomId")));
            }else{
                Log.e("EXTRAS room",""+extras.getString("roomId"));
                Log.e("EXTRAS STATUS",""+extras.getBoolean("fromNotification"));
            }
        }else{
//            Toast.makeText(HomePageTabActivity.this,"Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

public void openChatRoom(long roomId){
        Log.d("LONG ROOM",""+roomId);
        QiscusRxExecutor.execute(QiscusApi.getInstance().getChatRoom(roomId),
        new QiscusRxExecutor.Listener<QiscusChatRoom>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QiscusChatRoom qiscusChatRoom) {
                startActivity(GroupRoomActivity.
                        generateIntent(HomePageTabActivity.this, qiscusChatRoom));
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: how about making `intent.putExtras` as a `Map<NotificationId , UniqueId>`?

Comment: you need to make static map list and store id with their value. whenever you get the `id`  add in the `map` .

Comment: Can you give me some example how to do it ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved, i only changed the request code from 0 to a unique number. In my case i put the room id to the request code.

Before :

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

After :

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Integer.valueOf(roomId), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wish the following can help.

First,try to use setAction on the intent to a unique value so that there will be no matching PendingIntents.

```
    intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Second, set the flag of getActivity method to 0 instead of PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT.

PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT will update the extra data.

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: While setting the action like this will indeed make every intent unique, a more correct strategy would be to set the data element on the intent to a URI that represents the object in the database, based on the Room ID variable.